# SQL difference per row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am currently storing the value of a people counter entering into a shop, each shop has its own ID. Currently I have only stored 2 but am planning on adding in the region of 50.

Is there any way to calculate the number of people entering in each month using SQL and also have a total value for each month?

I also need a way to calculate an average for a month or two if a reading has been missed. So if May's reading was null then it would do 'Jun - Apr / 2'. Is this possible too?

```
_____ Readings ___________________

ID = 1 c/o - 90   | ID = 2 c/o - 190 | ID = 3 c/o - 50
ID = 1 Apr - 100  | ID = 2 Apr - 200 | ID = 3 Apr - 100
ID = 1 May - 120  | ID = 2 May - 230 | ID = 3 May - missed
ID = 1 Jun - 130  | ID = 2 Jun - 260 | ID = 3 Jun - 200
ID = 1 Jul - 140  | ID = 2 Jul - 280 | ID = 3 Jul - 300

_____ Output _____________________

ID = 1    |  ID = 2   |  ID = 3  | Total
          |           |          |
Apr - 10  | Apr - 10  | Apr - 50 | Apr - 70
May - 20  | May - 30  | May - 50 | May - 100
Jun - 10  | Jun - 30  | Jun - 50 | Jun - 90
Jul - 10  | Jul - 20  | Jul - 100| Jul - 130
```

The table has the headings: storeID, readDate, readValue.

Comment: May I ask why would May be "missed" for shop ID #3? This leads me to believe that it's possible to "miss" May and June so your calculation would then have to be 'Jul - Apr / 2'? This sort of issue would be absolutely maddening to figure out using pure SQL. If you are open to it then PHP would be a good place to put such logic.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Since someone is responsible for inputting values into the table through an online form its possible for people to forget or miss it due to illness. Other meters would be only reading on a quarterly basis due to little usage. I'm totally open to using PHP or JS to get this, I just dont know where to being.

Comment: @TakeoGFX can you make a export off the table 'Readings' and place the create table statement and data (insert statements) in the question because the text table is missing table headers..

Comment: I see. Will the readings cross into yearly boundaries? How would you handle `Nov 2016 - 50, Dec 2016 - missed, Jan 2017 - missed, Feb 2017 - missed, March 2017 - 950`? Is **all** of the data **always** going to be displayed on one page or will users be allowed to specify a date range? Pagination? It might be worthwhile to push back at the client and just provide an "N/A" if a month was completely missed because at least then they will know to go back and correct the data rather than always have the issues masked. Also, what happens if Shop #4 **NEVER EVER** records their numbers?

Comment: Also, the user should divide the quarterly readings by 3 and manually enter it for each month. Bad data = bad experience. Simple as that. As soon as something happens which you did not anticipate then your work gets blamed instead of the meter-reader person.

Comment: Hello? 9 more chars required...

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Apologies, had a meeting in work. The users will specify a date range which they can then see the number of clients. I cannot foresee a time in which a store does not record their numbers for more than a period of 5 months. I would rather have the system do the leg work, from what I've experiences users can be one of the weakest links.

Comment: You are correct, they are the weakest link and they will gloriously upset you one of these days. Anyways, the only way in which I see this working flawlessly is if you (1) Extract all of the monthly data from the DB (2) In PHP, run a loop of Jan - Dec (3) Within the PHP month loop, loop the monthly DB data and fill in any gaps with nulls such as `2016 May - null` (4) Loop the monthly DB data again and keep track of when there is data vs null, keep looping until you find another piece of data and backfill the nulls (5) Filter the data in PHP based on the user's date range.

Comment: I urge you to reconsider but I'm not the one in control of your payroll. Good luck